# Trouble with Microsoft Macros. Runtime Error 5941

Tags: vba, ms-word

Hi I am getting an error for this. I have tried both of the following examples. Please let me know if you know what's wrong. Thanks!

```
Sub Spanish()
'
' Spanish Macro
'
'
    Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks
    Selection.Range.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Application.Quit
End Sub
Sub Algebra()
'
' Algebra Macro
'
'
    Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks
    Selection.Range.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably because `Selection.Range` doesn't contain any hyperlinks.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code and check the actual values?

Comment: "I am getting an error" - this is not a useful description of what happens when you run your code. *What specific error* do you get (in words, not the numeric code), and on which line?

Comment: It says Run Time error 5842

Comment: I don’t know code sorry. I just pressed record and it worked. It only doesn’t work if u had just opened the document. If you click a link manually and then do the macro, it will work

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't going to do what you think it will.

Both routines do exactly the same thing, action any selected hyperlink and shut Word down.

The first line, `Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks`, has no relevance to following a hyperlink, and should be removed.

I suspect that you intended the second line, `Selection.Range.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True`, to open something specific. It won't. It will simply execute whatever hyperlink you currently have selected, or create an error if your selection doesn't contain a hyperlink. Essentially you have just created a long winded way of pressing Ctrl whilst clicking on a hyperlink.

The final two lines will shut Word down completely. Is that really what you want to happen?

To execute a specific hyperlink in Word you should use the [`FollowHyperlink method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.followhyperlink), for example:

```
ActiveDocument.FollowHyperlink Address:="https://stackoverflow.com/", NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
```

> "I don’t know code sorry. I just pressed record and it worked."

You don't need to know code to realize that what you recorded isn't going to work as you intended. The two routines were presumably meant to open different links, but just a quick read of the recorded code should have told you they weren't going to do that. If they did they would include the link you wanted to follow.

My advice to you would be to only use what you understand. If you want to use code with Word then invest some time in learning how to do it. There are plenty of online resources to learn VBA, including online courses. Although most are aimed at Excel rather then Word they will still be valuable.

But don't just use the macro recorder and hope it will work.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Yes, I want it to close word after.